# Read Integers From a File Into A Struct with Separate Member Variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, struct

I have a file with this data in it:

```
3
0 0.5
1 0.23
100 -0.5

2
1 0.01
6 -0.55
```

I have a private struct and list for two private member x and y variables:

```
struct FTerm {
    int m_delay;
    double m_weight;
};

std::list<FTerm> m_xterms;
std::list<FTerm> m_yterms;
```

The result should contain

```
for 3 m_xterms:
m_delay contains 0, 1, 100
m_weight contains 0.5, 0.23, -0.5

for 2 m_yterms:
m_delay contains 1, 6
m_weight contains 0.01, -0.55
```

So far I have this:

```
ifstream filt(dlg.GetPathName());
    if (filt.fail())
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Failed to open filter transfer equation file");
        return;
    }

    int numXTerms;
    string line;

    while (getline(filt, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        FTerm term;
        while (iss >> numXTerms)
        {
            filt >> numXTerms >> term.m_delay >> term.m_weight;
            m_xterms.resize(numXTerms);
            m_xterms.push_back(term);
        }

    }
```

From debugging this is what I get so I am not sure it is actually working:

[image: debug]

I also need to figure out how to get the Y values after the line break, is there a way to check for the line break and write another while loop?

Comment: You should overload `operator>>` in your structure to read in values from a stream.  This would help.

Comment: You don't need getline for this, but you do need to rethink your logic a bit.  You want to read a number, then you want to loop that many times reading pairs of numbers.  If you only use formatted input you don't need to care about the extra whitespace from the empty line.

Comment: The combination of resize + push_back is also a bit odd.  push_back will add a new item, you don't need resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things not quite right:

- Since the number of terms is known a for loop would probably work better
- vector would probably work better than list.
- you can extract the data directly to the objects without the added expense of a stringstream

Something like this should work:

```
std::vector<FTerm> m_xterms;
std::vector<FTerm> m_yterms;
int numFTerms;
std::string line;
filt >> numFTerms;
m_xterms.resize(numFTerms);

for (int i = 0; i < numFTerms; i++)
{
    FTerm term;
    filt >> term.m_delay >> term.m_weight;
    m_xterms[i] = term;
}
//ignore empty line
filt.ignore(1);
filt >> numFTerms;
m_yterms.resize(numFTerms);
for (int i = 0; i < numFTerms; i++)
{
    FTerm term;
    filt >> term.m_delay >> term.m_weight;
    m_yterms[i] = term;
}
```